# Missing DYSM Error on multiple Target in Fabric and Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios8, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

In my app there are two targets:

```
 Target 1 : MyApp - com.app.myapp
 Target 2 : MyAppQA  - com.app.myappQa
```

Email Id used for `Fabric` registration is `same` for both targets.

I have created two apps using `Fabric mac app`.

In `MyApp` Target Fabric is catching all the crash and working fine.
But When I run using target `MyAppQA` then I am getting `Missing DYSM file error.`

[image]

I am not able to get why crash is not captured in my second target.

Here is the method which I tried:

1. BitCode - Disabled (Although I am not using bitcode but even then I crosschecked)
2. Debug Information Format - Set to  DWARF with dSYM File (Both release and debug)
3. Tried uploading manually DYSM file (I got the dysm file by Archiving the project and then Selection ShowPackageContents from right ClickMenu)

I have tried all the possible solution available on internet. And also I don't want to manually update the dysm as I don't have iTunesConnect Account right now.

Comment: Please check crash logs are displayed in fabic dashboard??

Comment: @MonikaPatel no I am not getting any crash logs in Dashboard.

Comment: I already integrate crashlytics before 2 days. And It was integrated sucessfully. Wait I will provide all steps in detail

Comment: Please check my answer @RahulMishra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step to integrate Crashlytics:-

1.Add below cocoa pod

```
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
```

2.Add a Run Script into Build Phase(For this step you must have login into fabric than get API key)

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run" 8252525b24e2d6fagsdg101ea7faf49edefa84ff3ec342b0dgsdrergadc2bd8agsdg50671jhga2ee8c017ddgsdg33fbbb
```

3.Add Your API Key into info.plist file

```
 <key>Fabric</key>
    <dict>
     <key>APIKey</key>
     <string>your_key</string>
     <key>Kits</key>
        <array>
         <dict>
            <key>KitInfo</key>
         <dict/>
        <key>KitName</key>
            <string>Crashlytics</string>
        </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
```

4.Add below code in AppDelegate file

AppDelegate.h:-

```
#import <Fabric/Fabric.h>
#import <Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h>
```

AppDelegate.m:-

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class]]]
}
```

5.For force crash write below code on any button click event of view controller,can not write into app delegate file

```
[[Crashlytics sharedInstance] crash];
```

6.Change build setting:

```
 click on project target >>   Build setting >>  Chnage value of “Debug information Format” set it to “DWARF with dSYM file”
 click on project >>   Build setting >>  Chnage value of “Debug information Format” set it to “DWARF with dSYM file”
```

7.How to crash app

```
 Xcode's debugger prevents us from processing crash reports. 

  To make sure a crash is reported during your simulator testing:
   ⁃    Launch simulator (Run your project and install app in simulator)
   ⁃    Press stop (stop from Xcode )
   ⁃    Launch your app and force a crash (Now do not run project, just open simulator and launch your app from simulator and press button that u write code for crash ` [[Crashlytics sharedInstance] crash];`)
   ⁃    Relaunch the app from simulator (again run app from simulator not from Xcode project)
   ⁃    See the crash report in the web dashboard
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was missing quotes in Run Script Phase may be due this I was not getting DYSM file. @MonikaPatel

Comment: WEL COME @RahulMishra

Answer (score 3):

Mike from Fabric here.

Once the dSYM is uploaded, we will start reprocessing any crashes from the last 7 days, so it should be visible by now.

For uploading dSYMs, including seeing any errors with the upload flow, you can use the `upload-symbols` script located in the Fabric OS X app at `Fabric.app/Contents/MacOS/upload-symbols` and in the Fabric CocoaPod payload at `$PODS_ROOT/Fabric/upload-symbols`

Run the script with the following to upload all dSYMs from a given folder:

```
find <directory-to-search-for-dsyms> -name "*.dSYM" | xargs -I \{\} /path/to/upload-symbols -a <api-key> -p <platform> \{\}
```

[Documentation reference.](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/missing-dsyms.html#upload-symbols-script)

Comment: thanks mike for giving your time. sorry for late response. Although I made some changes in project setting and it works. I Disabled Bit Code and changed the Debug Information Format to DWARF with dysm file for both debug and Release.

I tried your manual uploading way and it also works. :)

Comment: Hi @Mike,
I am doing this run script very first time.

Would be a favor if you can give an example.
thanks

Comment: @MuhammadJabbar You should probably make a new question so that any discussion is not conflated with uploading dSYMs via the upload-symbols script.

Comment: Hi @MikeBonnell,

Thanks for your reply. I found the solution.

Comment: @MikeBonnell dsym's location will be created at runtime.Then how can i specify it in runscript?  Given that ,derived data folders are not static and will be created every time we run the app.Correct me if im wrong?