# iOS (Fabric): Crashlytics crashing app on launch

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I have updated the Crashlytics but still I am getting this error on launch:

> Error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FABException',
>   reason: '[Fabric] It appears that "Crashlytics" is not a valid Fabric
>   Kit. Please make sure you only pass Fabric Kits to [Fabric with:].'

Here is my code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

         Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
         return true
    }
```

Comment: U get crash log in Crashlytics??

Comment: @MonikaPatel No these are device logs.. App crash on launch and if i comment `Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])`; App works fine.

Comment: Please check my answer, i added in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38825229/fabric-missing-dysm-error-on-multiple-target-objective-c/39543256#39543256  @Muhammad Umair

Comment: @MonikaPatel I am not using pods and i am getting this error in swift. And I have checked my info.plist file; all the values there in my info.plist file.

Comment: @MonikaPatel any other suggestion or solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS: '\[Fabric\] It appears that "Crashlytics" is not a valid Fabric Kit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39719238/ios-fabric-it-appears-that-crashlytics-is-not-a-valid-fabric-kit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending 7 hours, I am able to solve the problem. Problem is: there are 2 Crashlytics files are in my code which are causing this problem. To solve the problem, I have deleted the older file and again integrate the Crashlytics.

Answer (score 5):

I was having a crash on the same line, and it was because I called it BEFORE FirebaseApp.configure().

For anyone having the same issue, make sure you call them in this order:

```
FirebaseApp.configure()
Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a real life saver.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
      Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
      return true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code snippet, it may help:

***For Swift:***

```
//import related frameworks

import Fabric

import Crashlytics

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    Fabric.with([Crashlytics()])
    //... your initialization code
    return true
}
```

***For Objective-C:***

```
#import <Fabric/Fabric.h>
#import <Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h>

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
     [Fabric with:@[CrashlyticsKit]];
     //... your initialization code
   return YES;
}
```

Comment: My app is crashing on this line of code: `Fabric.with([Crashlytics()])`