# iOS: '[Fabric] It appears that "Crashlytics" is not a valid Fabric Kit

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I have updated the `Crashlytics` but still I am getting this error on launch:

> Error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FABException',
>   reason: '[Fabric] It appears that "Crashlytics" is not a valid Fabric
>   Kit. Please make sure you only pass Fabric Kits to [Fabric with:].'

**Here is my code**:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
         Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
         return true
   }
```

Comment: Is there any older version of Crashlytics added in your frameworks???

Comment: No I am using updated version of Crashlytics but in previous version it has the older version. I have update the Crashlytics. Even i have removed the crashlytics from code and reinstall it from scratch. But still it is crashing.

Comment: check in your target -> general -> linked Frameworks and Libraries ... if crashalytics is there than remove it

Comment: It is throwing this error now : `Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Fabric", referenced from:
      type metadata accessor for __ObjC.Fabric in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Crashlytics", referenced from:
      type metadata accessor for __ObjC.Crashlytics in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: may be this should work http://stackoverflow.com/a/37370753/4601170

Comment: No it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

use this line of code. after a long try i found this solution xcode7, swift2/3

```
    Fabric.with([Crashlytics()])
```

i hope it will fix your bug.

Answer (score -1):

Please try:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?)
-> Bool 
{
            // Override point for customization after application launch.
             Fabric.with([Crashlytics.class])  // <=========
             return true    
}
```